# How to embed tab bar controller with a split view controller in swift?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, swift2

im guessing there needs to be changes in the app delegate? Thanks for the help!

Comment: maybe this will help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29723231/use-uitabbarviewcontroller-in-portrait-but-uisplitviewcontroller-in-landscape-in

Answer (score 14, accepted):

1) Create a sample Master/Detail via xcode

2) Drag a `TabBarController` on the storyboard

3) Change the `TabBarController` to the initial view controller.

4) Control Drag from the `TabBarController` to the `SplitViewController`

5) Assign a title to the `SplitViewController` in the storyboard

6) In the app delegate replace the reference to the `SplitViewController` as follows.

```
let tabBarViewController = self.window!.rootViewController as! UITabBarController
print(tabBarViewController.viewControllers?.count)
var splitViewController:UISplitViewController? = nil
for viewController in tabBarViewController.viewControllers! {
if viewController.title == "Master" {
    splitViewController = viewController as? UISplitViewController
}
}

let navigationController = splitViewController!.viewControllers[splitViewController!.viewControllers.count-1] as! UINavigationController
navigationController.topViewController!.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = splitViewController!.displayModeButtonItem()
splitViewController!.delegate = self
```